# For a given symmetric and positive definite matrix M, find matrix C which fulfills CC^T = M and C^TC = D

Tags: linear-algebra

D is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of M. Is it solvable and if so, how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is a square matrix, the equation is always solvable. Let $M=QDQ^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation. Then $C=QD^{1/2}$ is a solution, where $D^{1/2}$ denotes the entrywise square root of $D$.

Comment: Do you mean "if M  is a square matrix..."? And doesn't the fact that M is symmetric and positive definite infer that?

Comment: @Leo I thought you probably meant that the eigenvalues of $M$ form a subset of the diagonal elements of $D$. Therefore $C$ might be rectangular.